# Is there a way for a client side app to work with server, which doesn't have CORS set

Tags: javascript, browser, cors, xmlhttprequest

I want to make a call to a 3rd party desktop app running, in a user's system, which has a port open at 3000, and when user opens my website, I make a request to his localhost:3000 port and fetch data, but the 3rd party app doesn't have response headers set for CORS, so I am not able to use this strategy to sync, Do anyone know a way to do this?
In here, I have used ngrok to tunnel and still not able to do it.

```
xhr.open("POST", 'https://576b4cc1.ngrok.io', true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
        console.log("In ready state exchange: " + xhr.responseText);
        resolve();
    }
}
xhr.onload = function (data) {
    console.log("In onload : " + data);
}
xhr.onerror = function (err) {
    console.log("In error: " + JSON.stringify(err, ["message", "arguments", "type", "name"]));
    console.log('Data incase : ' + xhr.statusText);
}
xhr.send(reqObj.data);
```

Comment: The CORS requirement is a security measure. There is no work-around.

Comment: In an ideal situation, you would setup a proxy that does handle the proper CORS headers and let that relay the requests to the 3rd party app. If the 3rd party app is not planning on making its app more secure by adding CORS headers to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

You could launch your browser from command line with the flag for disabling web security, for example with chrome you can do the following:

```
chrome --disable-web-security
```

There are also chrome plugins who allows you to do this like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: May I add that this is highly risky and should never be used if you want others to use and rely on your app. Safer way would be to setup a proxy server that does provide the proper CORS headers, which then in turn communicates with the external 3rd party app.